# node.js req.body shows empty

Tags: node.js, express

Student list showing like this and the problem happened when I click detail button(no req.body data, console.log(req.body) shows [])
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoOjh.png)

student.jade

```
extends layout

block content
    h1 Student list
    .studentlist
       table
            thead
                tr
                    th name
                    th age
            tbody               
                 each mongo_result, i in slist
                     form(action='/detail', method="POST") 
                        tr                                                   
                            td(type="text" name="name")= mongo_result.name
                            td(type="text" age="age")= mongo_result.age                             
                                button.btn-primary(type="submit" width='50' height='50') Detail
```

app.js

```
    app.use(express.favicon());
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.urlencoded());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(require('stylus').middleware(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.post('/detail', (req, res) => {    
//var data = res.json({ result: result });
console.log(req.body);
dbs.collection('slist').find({ name: req.body.name, age:1}).toArray((err, docs) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err)
    console.log(docs);
    res.render('detail', { title: 'Detail', year: new Date().getFullYear(), message: 'Detail of student', detail: docs});
}); 


})
```

I have tried all stuffs from other posts but
I don't still get answers for it.
I am creating a detail page for students and when I try it, req.body is always empty.(each table's td will have name and age and I want to send it when button clicked)
Any ideas for me?
Thank you for reading.

Comment: Well if you added the post route '/detail' inside the pug template, it won't work for sure, maybe that's just an error, but until you fix it i can not really help you. Code is a mess by the look of it(right now)

Comment: post route 'detail' is in app.js and I am using Visual Studio with it.

Comment: Ok where does mongo_result come from ? is it empty ?

Comment: When I click button named Detail, console.log(req.body); shows only empty.

Comment: The student list shows correctly with each button named Detail. When I click the button, /detail post works but no req.body data .

Comment: I added student list picture

Comment: Is there any reason why you have `app.router`? If it's not used, remove it from yor app.js. Also note that you have a lot of parsers, just use `bodyPaser.json` and `bodyParser.urlencoded`, otherwise requests are parsed more than once.

Comment: what he said indeed, and you should be using a get route for that, no need to post a form to get to a details page

Comment: Thank you. I will try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that form action does not contain table elements.

just use styled html instead of table (such as div div div!)